# Recurrent Spiking Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, biological-neural-network

Where can I find an exact definition of recurrent spiking neural networks work and how do they work? I tried google and it just shows a lot of papers and articles to implement these but no proper definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spiking neural networks are artificial neural networks that more closely mimic natural neural networks.
RNNs are neural networks where connections between nodes form a directed graph.In RNNs the output from the previous step is fed as input to the current step.

Recurrent Spiking Neural Networks are a combination of both. It makes a RNN on the pattern of human brain.Recurrent Spiking Neural Networks are the closest thing to human brain.